# Finite natural summation that leads to double exponential results

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, exponentiation

We know that $$f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}=2^n$$ and $$g(n)=\sum_{i=0}^ni\binom{n}{i}=n2^{n-1}.$$

Are there any finite natural sums that lead to $2^{2^n}$ or $2^n2^{2^{n-1}}$ results other than $f(2^n)$ and $g(2^n)$ type ones?

In general, I do not want results that involve composition of functions that lead to $2^{2^n}$ results. For instance, if $h(n)=2^n$ then $h(2^n)=2^{2^n}$ is obvious and I want to avoid such trivialities.

If the summation remains over $n^t$ terms for fixed $t\in\Bbb N$, that is an added bonus.

Comment: I think the second is $\sum_{i=0}^{n}i\binom{n}{i}=n2^{n-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Well there is this:

$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} 2^k = \frac{2^N -1}{2-1} = 2^N -1$

So if you set : $h(N) = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} 2^k$ you get:

$h(2^n) = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} 2^k = 2^{2^n}$

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No, this is not what I want.